# snapshot.data.length in the itemcount does not work: "The getter 'length' was called on null"

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch documents from firestore with the following code:

```
 Future getCategories() async {
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("categories").getDocuments();
    return qn.documents;
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child:FutureBuilder(
        future:getCategories(),
        builder:(context, snapshot){
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
            return Center(
              child:Text("Loading...")
            );
         }
         else
         {
           return GridView.builder(
             itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
             gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                 crossAxisSpacing: 6.0, mainAxisSpacing: 6.0, crossAxisCount: 2),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return SingleCategory(
                  category_name:  snapshot.data[index].data["title"],
                  category_picture: snapshot.data[index].data["picture"],
                );
              }
           );
         }
        }
      )
    );
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

> I/flutter ( 7555): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
>   ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter
>   ( 7555): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building
>   FutureBuilder(dirty, state: I/flutter ( 7555):
>   _FutureBuilderState#c3e7b): I/flutter ( 7555): The getter 'length' was called on null. I/flutter ( 7555): Receiver: null
>   I/flutter ( 7555): Tried calling: length I/flutter ( 7555):  I/flutter
>   ( 7555): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: I/flutter
>   ( 7555): #0      Object.noSuchMethod
>   (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Error message is explicit, your `snapshot.data` is null. Do not await the result if you use a `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: I was using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6uBjMFoyT-I. Why would await not work with FutureBuilder? Btw, I removed await and I am still getting the same error

Comment: @bangbang Just turn on the debugger and check the `snapshot` object. Pay attention to the fields `snapshot.error` and `snapshot.connectionState`

Comment: sorry I mean you don't necessarily need a `FutureBuilder` as you already get the result right after your `await` statement. `var result = await getCategories(); print('done');` should be the same as `getCategories().then((result) { print('done'); })` which is the same as `FutureBuilder<Categories>( future: getCategories(), builder: (context, snapshot){ print('done'); } );`. But indeed this may not be the source of your problem.

Comment: Here's what I found: connection state is ConnectionState.waiting
 Snapshot error  is PlatformException(Error performing getDocuments, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., null)

Comment: Here are my firestore rule: 

service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {

      allow read, write: if false;

    }
  }
}

It seems okay. Why is the permission denied?

Comment: I got the same issue, have you resolved this?

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
future: getData(),
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<User>> snapshot)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the complete solution for api integration using http

1. Please add the http dependency:
   http: ^0.13.3
2. import the http package:
   import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
3. Add Internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml.
4. Here is the complete code of Fetch data from Api using http.

   ```
     import 'dart:convert';
     import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

     void main() {
       runApp(MyApp());
     }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
         @override
         Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           return MaterialApp(
                title: 'Food recipe',
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                theme: ThemeData(
                    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
                    primaryColor: Colors.white,
                    textTheme: TextTheme(
                    bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          home: DataFromApi(),
       );
      }
     }

     class DataFromApi extends StatefulWidget {
        @override
       _DataFromApiState createState() => _DataFromApiState();
      }         

     class _DataFromApiState extends State<DataFromApi> {
      Future<List<Data>> getData() async {
       var response =
        await http.get(Uri.https('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', 'users'));
        var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
       List<Data> dataList = [];
       for (var u in jsonData) {
            Data data = Data(u["name"], u["phone"], u["email"]);
            dataList.add(data);
        }
       print(dataList.length);
       return dataList;
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
           title: Text("Data Fetch"),
       ),
      body: Container(
          child: Card(
            child: FutureBuilder<List<Data>>(
           future: getData(),
           builder: (context, snapshot) {
               if (snapshot.data == null) {
                return Container(
               child: Text("Loading"),
               );
            }else{
               return ListView.builder(
                     itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                     itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                       return ListTile(
                           title: Column(
                           children: [
                                 Text(snapshot.data![i].name),
                                 Text(snapshot.data![i].phone),
                                 Text(snapshot.data![i].email),
                           ],
                         ),
                       );
                    });
                }
             },
          ),
         ),
       ));
    }
   }

   class Data {
     final String name, phone, email;

     Data(this.name, this.phone, this.email);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

As we found out in the comments, you are using an auth rule, which denies access for all requests:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
       allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

I think you wanted to write something like this (read only mode):

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
       allow read;
       allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Try this rule

Comment: Great catch Kirill!

Comment: That's what i needed ! Perfect

Answer (score 2):

You can use **dynamic**

```
     child: FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
          future: getApiData(),
           ...
           ...
```

Its works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should add initialData attribute in FutureBuilder widget and set it to [] empty list. For example:

```
FutureBuilder(  // only add initialData: []
    initilData: [],  // this is vital to get rid of null length error
    future:getCategories(),
    builder:(context, snapshot){
      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
        return Center(
          child:Text("Loading...")
        );
     } // and same code goes below
```

So, our main aim to prevent null length error, by adding initialData property to empty array can solve our problem.
Here is the official definition of this property---

> The data that will be used to create the snapshots provided until a
> non-null future has completed.
> also we can add some loading widget to not showing empty screen to the user.

*We can add a condition "when the snapshot has data which is equal to empty array (or data.length == 0) if it is then show loading widget else show list".*

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem try to use this.

```
 builder:(ctx, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot)
```

full StreamBuilder code with itemCount of listView if you need the length of documents

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('categories').snapshots(),
        builder:
            (ctx, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Text('sample'));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use the hasData parameter of snapshot.

```
if (snapshot.hasData) { return GridViewBuilder(...);}
```